# Does Drupal ignore <b> (bold) tags?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have custom content type with body made of full html. I am using the bold tag to emphasize a word, but it is not displayed as bold. It thought it might be the Google font I used, so I disabled it, but I still get the issue.

I checked the page source:

```
    <div id="begin_block">
      <div id="fw_begin"><h2>Find words <b>beginning</b> with:</h2></div>
        <div id="inp_begin"><input type="text" /></div>
        <div id="aft_begin">(max. 5 characters)</div>
        <div id="but_begin"><button type="button">Go</button></div>
    </div>
```

But I still get:

[image]

What could be causing this issue? Is it Drupal related?

Comment: If you downvote this question, can you at least explain why? Drupal does perform HTML transformation (newlines etc...) when configured so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, the answer to the question is no. This is was [caused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751679/what-could-cause-a-bold-tag-b-to-be-ignored#comment12405173_9751679) by the `reset.css` delivered in the Versatile theme.